# How to create nodes to append when using XML::LibXML to write XML?

Tags: perl, libxml2

I am creating an XML document and adding a complicated node to it in a loop, similar to the following example.

The following works, but feels kludgy in how it creates `$row_template`.  Is there not some more specific way to create a document fragment to reuse from an xml string?

```
use 5.022;
use warnings;
use XML::LibXML;

my $xml = '<?xml version="1.0"?><RootNode><Outer1><Outer2/></Outer1></RootNode>';
my $row_parent_xpath = '//Outer2';
my $row_xml = '<DetailNode><Field1/><Field2/></DetailNode>';

# create the document
my $doc = XML::LibXML->load_xml('string' => $xml);
# find where we will be inserting nodes
my ($parent) = $doc->findnodes($row_parent_xpath);

# create a template for the nodes to insert
my $row_template = XML::LibXML->load_xml('string' => $row_xml)->documentElement;
$row_template->setOwnerDocument($doc);

for my $row_data ({field1=>'Foo',field2=>'Bar'}, {field1=>'Baz',field2=>'Quux'}) {
    my $row = $row_template->cloneNode(1);
    $parent->appendChild($row);
    $_->appendChild($doc->createTextNode($row_data->{field1})) for $row->findnodes('Field1');
    $_->appendChild($doc->createTextNode($row_data->{field2})) for $row->findnodes('Field2');
}

say $doc->toString(1);
```

output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<RootNode>
  <Outer1>
    <Outer2>
      <DetailNode>
        <Field1>Foo</Field1>
        <Field2>Bar</Field2>
      </DetailNode>
      <DetailNode>
        <Field1>Baz</Field1>
        <Field2>Quux</Field2>
      </DetailNode>
    </Outer2>
  </Outer1>
</RootNode>
```

Comment: This is basically how any XML generation I've done goes. The Mojo::DOM [new_tag](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::DOM#new_tag) method can make it slightly nicer, but usually I end up just using an XML-escaping templater (like Mojo::Template with auto_escape => 1).

Comment: Why not create a sub that provides a suitable interface for what you want to do?

Comment: You can write `$_->appendText(...)` instead of `$_->appendChild($doc->createTextNode(...))`. Another useful method is `appendTextChild`. Other than that, I'm not sure how you'd expect to simplify the code.

Comment: @nwellnhof the thing that is bothering me is not seeing something to just create the document fragment, having to call load_xml and then throw away the document it creates and just keep the root element.  It seems wrong that libxml has a document fragment type but seemingly no direct way to create one, or way to parse an xml fragment and produce just a node owned by an existing document.

Comment: libxml2 has [`xmlParseBalancedChunkMemory`](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-parser.html#xmlParseBalancedChunkMemory) which also takes a document. XML::LibXML has [`parse_balanced_chunk`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-LibXML/lib/XML/LibXML/Parser.pod#parse_balanced_chunk) but this doesn't allow to set the document. AFAIK, you don't have to call `setOwnerDocument` anyway but it should be more performant if you do.

Comment: @nwellnhof that looks like what I was looking for and not finding.  can you make it an answer?  (I was having weird problems when I didn't setOwnerDocument)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

libxml2 has [`xmlParseBalancedChunkMemory`](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-parser.html#xmlParseBalancedChunkMemory) which also takes a document. XML::LibXML has [`parse_balanced_chunk`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-LibXML/lib/XML/LibXML/Parser.pod#parse_balanced_chunk) but this doesn't allow to set the document. I'm not sure whether you have to call `setOwnerDocument`. When appending the cloned node, the owner document should be set automatically.